# Push notifications swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS application that I am developing using swift 3 on the front end but using php and MySQL on the backend. However, I'm still inexperienced with iOS development. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to handle push notifications?

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/ ?

Comment: I have not, I'm really just asking for what people found as the best method to send dynamic notifications such as someone comment on anothers post

Comment: Because there is no other better way

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your Push Notifications by yourself in your server ([RMSPushNotificationsBundle](https://github.com/richsage/RMSPushNotificationsBundle) Github project will help you doing it if you are using PHP).

But it will be super easy to use Firebase Messaging or Parse Push virtualization.

Firebase:
You will be able to use the [fcm-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push) Node.js module if you are willing to deploy a Node.js server beside a Firebase account.

You will just need to create an Application in Firebase, and then in Apple's Developers site you can apply your Push Notifications certificate.

Read these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

**EDIT**: You can also use the Firebase RESTful API with PHP code instead of using the fcm-push module I've suggested.

More reading material: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message